# Unable to use fn:cast and castable in XSLT

Tags: validation, date, xslt, xslt-1.0, ibm-datapower

I am trying to convert a string to date using castable function in XSLT. But i am getting a parsing error. I am using DataPower XI52 version 6.0.1.0. Does XI52 support this function?

Sample XML:

```
<Input><Date>2011-31-12</Date></Input>
```

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="Date" select="Input/Date"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="fn:cast($Date,'xs:string','xs:date', true())"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (as it seems) you are trying to determine if the input contains a valid date - i.e. the equivalent of:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="Date" select="Input/Date"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$Date castable as xs:date"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then try the following:

**XSLT 1.0 (+ EXSLT)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
extension-element-prefixes="date">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="Date" select="Input/Date"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="boolean(date:date($Date))"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should work with any XSLT 1.0 processor that supports the EXSLT date:date() extension function, incl. IBM DataPower.

Note however, that it does NOT work with Saxon 6.5.5 that will happily output `2011-31-12` as the result of `<xsl:value-of select="date:date('2011-31-12')"/>` - despite the [specification](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/date/index.html) prescribing an empty string as the required result in this case.

Comment: Thanks!! Micheal, i have implemented this in my code and it works fine.

Comment: @OmkarVenkata Please close this question, then.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from the [release notes](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wsdatap/v6r0m1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.dp.xi.doc%2FrelnotesXI.html), DataPower only supports XSLT version 1.0.  It supports XPath 2.0 functions but only as part of XQuery, not XSLT.

Comment: Hi Ian, Thanks for your suggestion. Could you please suggest me a way how to convert the string data to date in xslt

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no function fn:cast() in any version of XSLT/XPath. Perhaps you are thinking of the "cast as" operator in XPath 2.0: `Input/Date cast as xs:date`.

Secondly, Datapower does not support XPath 2.0 in XSLT. XPath 2.0 is supported in XQuery only.

Refer Answer from [Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25609239/3557336)

Comment: HI Micheal, I have seen fn:cast in IBM datapower infocenter under XSLT and XPath extensions. Under the examples section of this function I could see the type supported in XPath 1.0.Not sure if my understanding is correct. Also could you please let me know how to handle above data type conversion in xslt

Comment: Sorry, can't help you on anything DataPower-specific. And since it's about 10 years since I used XSLT 1.0, there are other people who can  help you on that much better than I can.